# how to write this query in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I had used a query using `mysql_query()` and `mysql_connect()`, bun now i am using `PDO` in php

please help me, what is the best and fastest way for this query:

my old query was:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE publish = '1' 
    AND id IN 
        (SELECT product_id FROM category_controller WHERE category_id IN 
                (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE publish = '1'))";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

my new query is:

```
$PDO = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", 'root', '');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE publish = '1' 
    AND id IN 
        (SELECT product_id FROM category_controller WHERE category_id IN 
                (SELECT id FROM categories WHERE publish = '1'))";

$result = $PDO->query($sql);
```

but the both ways that i had used was very slowly beacuse there are more than 5000 records in `products` table.

please help me to find a new and fastest way to run this query.

Comment: You can probably replace those subqueries with JOINs.  Also, make sure `product_id`, `category_id`, `publish` have indexes.

Comment: Is your question about PDO syntax or query speed?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) maybe be useful

Comment: Did the `mysql_` version run faster than the `PDO` version?????

Comment: @RiggsFolly `but the both ways that i had used was very slowly`

Comment: This question is unclear, what do you mean when you say fastest? Fast to run? Fast to encode? PDO is an abstraction layer that represents a connection between PHP and a database server. `mysql_query()`is a function also deprecated in PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: excuse me, beacuse I am not english and I can not speak english good. sorry friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may speed this up by using the JOIN concept rather than all the sub queries like this.

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p
   JOIN category_controller cc ON cc.category_id = c.id
   JOIN categories c ON c.publish = 1
WHERE p.publish = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

PDO doesn't improve your speed, as I can see in this hard query.
You need to explode queries by parts, if you need to increase speed.
For expample:
1st query will get all id from your categories, and make array of ids.
2 query will get all product_id from cateogry_controller USING your array of ids from previous query `... WHERE category_id IN (implode(',',$arrayOfcats))`

Then do the same for products

Comment: this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: @CodeGodie, you r right, but i have edited my answer.

Comment: Not the best answer, but it is not a comment anymore, thanks for the edit.

Comment: are you sure is it faster than that query?